# fiber, homotopy fiber of spaces

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Suppose we have a pullback of topological spaces (CW-complexes) $B\rightarrow A\leftarrow C$ which I will denote by $D$.

**Assumptions**

1. The induced map $D\rightarrow C$ is a trivial fibration
2. The map $f:B\rightarrow A$ has weakly contractible fibers i.e., for any $a\in A$ we have $f^{-1}(a)\simeq \ast$
3. The induced map $D\rightarrow B$ induces an isomorphism in homology.
4. The map $C\rightarrow A$ induces a surjective map in homology.
5. We can assume that $A$ is simply connected.

**Question** 
What can we say about the map $B\rightarrow A$? Does it induce an isomorphism in homology?

**Edit:** The spaces $C,B$ are connected.

Comment: Doesn't the isomorphism on homology follow already from assumption 2 thanks to the Vietoris Begle theorem?

Comment: No, the Vietoris-Begle theorem only holds for proper maps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Counterexample:

Let $A=[0,1]$ with the usual topology, $B=C=[0,1]^{\delta}$ (this means the discrete topology). The maps $f:B \to A$ and $g:C \to A$ are the identity. Then $f^{-1} (t) = *$ for all $t \in A$, but $f$ is not a homology isomorphism, and $g$ is surjective in homology. Furthermore, the pullback $D$ is the diagonal in $B \times C$, hence it is also $[0,1]^{\delta}$. The two maps $D \to B$ and $D \to C$ are homeomorphisms, hence acyclic fibrations and homology equivalences.

Comment: Thank you, I forgot to say that the spaces B and C are connected.

Comment: @Ilias: Having B, C connected does not help. Just take the suspension of Johannes' example. Then B, C, D are connected with uncountable fundamental group and uncountable H_1, but A is still contractible. And if you want B, C to be simply connected, then just suspend once more.